# How to do composition in Kotlin like Groovy's << and >> operators

Tags: kotlin, groovy, composition

How can I chain/compose functions in Kotlin in a simple way, like e.g. in Groovy with the >> operator?
Groovy syntax (see http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html):

```
def plus2  = { it + 2 }
def times3 = { it * 3 }

// composition
def times3plus2 = plus2 << times3
assert times3plus2(3) == 11
assert times3plus2(4) == plus2(times3(4))

// reverse composition
assert times3plus2(3) == (times3 >> plus2)(3)
```

How to do the same in Kotlin?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932504/kotlin-higher-order-function-composition ?  See also https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-composition-in-standard-library/1683, https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/coding-kotlin-functional-style-is-it-possible/9194, https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/which-code-style-would-you-prefer/8936 &c.

Comment: Also see https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Callable%20references/Composition%20of%20functions/Composition%20of%20functions.kt

Comment: Also, a blast from the past https://gist.github.com/timyates/2300897

Comment: Thanks, it looks like more people thought about it but Kotlin just doesn’t provide it (yet?). It’s not my style to extend the language or create generic libs in my programs, so I’ll just stick to the alternatives (with intermediate variables or using let keyword)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such built-in feature in Kotlin language, but you can create extension functions on lambda to solve that problem:

```
/**
 * Extension function joins two functions, using the result of the first function as parameter
 * of the second one.
 */
infix fun <P1, R1, R2> ((P1) -> R1).then(f: (R1) -> R2): (P1) -> R2 {
    return { p1: P1 -> f(this(p1)) }
}

infix fun <R1, R2> (() -> R1).then(f: (R1) -> R2): () -> R2 {
    return { f(this()) }
}

/**
 * Extension function is the exact opposite of `then`, using the result of the second function
 * as parameter of the first one.
 */
infix fun <P1, R, P2> ((P1) -> R).compose(f: (P2) -> P1): (P2) -> R {
    return { p1: P2 -> this(f(p1)) }
}
```

Using those extension functions we can write code in Kotlin similar to yours:

```
val plus2: (Int) -> Int  = { it + 2 }
val times3: (Int) -> Int = { it * 3 }

// composition
val times3plus2 = plus2 compose times3
assert(times3plus2(3) == 11)
assert(times3plus2(4) == plus2(times3(4)))

// reverse composition
assert(times3plus2(3) == (times3 then plus2)(3))
```

P.S.: There is useful library, called [funKTionale](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Function-composition), it has the similar extension functions to compose functions - **forwardCompose** or **andThen**, and **compose**.